# How to use blurprint theme script into bigcommerce stencil Framwork format?

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce, stencils

My questions simple. I just want to use below  javascript code into the stencil framework  format

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var CartTotal = '%%GLOBAL_CartItemTotal%%';
var CustomerGroup = '%%GLOBAL_CustomerGroupName%%';
var CartTotal = CartTotal.replace('$','');
var CartTotal = CartTotal.replace(',','');
if(CartTotal >= 100.0) {
$('.CartTotalMessage').hide();
}
else {
if (CustomerGroup == "Wholesale") {
$('.ProceedToCheckout').hide();
$('.PayPalExpressCheckout').hide();
$('#CartHeader h2 img').hide();
$('.btn-secondary').hide();
$('a[title="Click here to proceed to checkout"]').hide();
}
else {
$('.CartTotalMessage').hide();
}
}
});
</script>
```

It's not working in stencil format I know there is need to use objects of stencil big. format  i have replaced  %%GLOBAL_CartItemTotal%%  into  {{cart.grand_total}} and %%GLOBAL_CustomerGroupName%% into  {{customer.customer_group_name}} but it's not working to hide checkout button untill order above $100  I need your help how I can achieve this.

Comment: It looks like you will need to find the page elements that contain the cart total and use that to set the variable instead of a global. For customer group, you can use {{customer.customer_group_name}} or {{customer.customer_group_id}}

Answer (score 0):

yes I have solved my problem convert js above like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var CartTotal = '{{cart.grand_total.formatted}}';
var CartTotal = CartTotal.replace('$','');
var CartTotal = CartTotal.replace(',','');
console.log(CartTotal);
if(CartTotal >= 100.0) {
   $('.CartTotalMessage').hide();
}
else {
  $('.CartTotalMessage').show();
  $('.PayPalExpressCheckout').hide();
  $('#CartHeader h2 img').hide();
  $('.btn-secondary').hide();
  $('a[title="Click here to proceed to checkout"]').hide();
}
});
```

Thanks for help